# IMIXS JSF example deployment with Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, imixs-workflow

I wanted to try IMIXS workflow solution.

I followed the steps mentioned on the below two links.
Sample Application - http://www.imixs.org/doc/sampleapplication.html
Glassfish deployment steps - http://www.imixs.org/doc/deployment/glassfish.html

When I try to deploy the war, I get the below error:

> remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer. Please see server.log for more details.
>
> PER01003: Deployment encountered SQL Exceptions:
>           PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE DOUBLEITEM (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ITEMNAME VARCHAR(255), ITEMVALUE FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))": java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Table/View 'DOUBLEITEM' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
>           PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE WRITEACCESS (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))": java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Table/View 'WRITEACCESS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
>   ...................................................
>   .....................................................
>   .......................................................

Something related to database table. Not sure how to get rid of this error.

Need help to get this working. I am no JEE developer, wanted to try out the solution.

Comment: Try to open an issue on the GitHub project site: https://github.com/imixs/imixs-jsf-example/issues

Answer (score 0):

If your are running on GlassFish4 than the Jersey Servlet class name in web.xml has changed from

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

to

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

You need to fix this in your web.xml for Glassfish4 and Payara Server.
In addition for GlassFish4 it can be necessary to disable the implicit-cdi flag. This allows to deploy EJBs in embedded jar files.

```
./asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false
```